# Get all the objects from state which is having multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Actually I have a state data which is an object , It has following structutre,

```
{  one : [ { abc:1 }, { abc: 2 }], two : [ { abc:3 }, { abc: 4 }, three : [ { abc:5 }, { abc: 6 }]]   }
```

So its like an arry of objects in an state object .

Now, I want to create an array of objects which will have all these objects .

So I want to have it like,

```
[{ abc:1 }, { abc: 2 },{ abc:3 }, { abc: 4 },{ abc:5 }, { abc: 6 }]
```

The way I tried is using `for loop`.

```
let quizCriteriaObj = [];

let low = this.props.lowQuizData["Low"];
let High = this.props.lowQuizData["High"];
let Medium = this.props.lowQuizData["Medium"];
console.log("data is ", low);

for (let i = 0; i <= low.length - 1; i++) {
    quizCriteriaObj.push(low[i]);
}
for (let i = 0; i <= High.length - 1; i++) {
    quizCriteriaObj.push(High[i]);
}
for (let i = 0; i <= Medium.length - 1; i++) {
    quizCriteriaObj.push(Medium[i]);
}
console.log(quizCriteriaObj);
```

I have taken each field aside from that object and using a for loop on every field. SO, It is working for me. But , I think this is not a proper solution for me .Is there any thing That I am doing wrong ?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If it works reliably, then you're probably not doing it wrong. There doesn't seem to be a real question here...

Comment: without seeing what you did, how can anyone say it's not a proper solution, considering it works

Comment: `The way I tried is using for loop` where is that code?

Comment: Okay I will update that code which Itried

Comment: by the way, your object is invalid

Comment: There seems to be a misplaced closing square bracket

Answer (score 3):

Modern javascript makes this trivial

Array.prototype.flat

> Please note: Array.prototype.flat is a stage 3 TC39 proposal, so is not part of the ECMAScript specification (yet)
>   It is supported in all modern browsers (and can be polyfilled for Microsofts attempts at browsers, both Internet Explorer and Edgey)

Note: I assume you mistyped the "source" object, because as it was, it was invalid

```js
let obj = {  
    one : [ 
        { abc:1 }, 
        { abc: 2 }
    ], 
    two : [ 
        { abc:3 }, 
        { abc: 4 }
    ],
    three : [ 
        { abc:5 }, 
        { abc: 6 }
    ]
}
let ftw = Object.values(obj).flat(); //<== single line of code is all you need
console.log(JSON.stringify(ftw))
```

Comment: [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) is experimental and not part of standard (only candidate)

Comment: Stage 3 as of May 2018 - how many proposals fail at stage 3? :D

Comment: @barbsan - I've added a caveat :p

Comment: I don't mean it can fail - but it may change and i.e. nodejs doesn't support it yet

Comment: @barbsan - Node 11 does support it (so did Node 10 IIRC) - that warning in MDN probably hasn't been updated since it was a strawman proposal :p (along with compatibility chart)

Comment: I'd stay clear of this solution @ganeshkaspate due to browser compatibility reasons, unless you know what you are doing :p

Comment: Nice one. I didn't actually know about `flat` yet :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.values` to convert the object into an array. Use `spread syntax` and `concat()` to flatten the array

```js
var obj ={"one":[{"abc":1},{"abc":2}],"two":[{"abc":3},{"abc":4}],"three":[{"abc":5},{"abc":6}]}

var result = [].concat(...Object.values(obj));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: can u explain in a bit ? it would be helpful for me in future,

Comment: Sure. You can use `Object.values` to extract all the values of the object. In your case, this will create a multidimensional array. You use `...` or `spread syntax` to reiterate each array element. Use `concat()` to add each element into one array :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop

```js
let obj = {  one : [ { abc:1 }, { abc: 2 }], two : [ { abc:3 }, { abc: 4 }], three : [ { abc:5 }, { abc: 6 }]   };

let result = [];
for (let key in obj) result = [...result, ...obj[key]];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You are going to iterate over each key value pair in object and concatenate every value in the resulting array. ... spreads the array into individual value which are objects here and combine all of them in one array.

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash is simple:

const obj = {  one : [ { abc:1 }, { abc: 2 }], two : [ { abc:3 }, { abc: 4 }, three : [ { abc:5 }, { abc: 6 }]]   }

_.flatten(obj)

// return => [{ abc:1 }, { abc: 2 },{ abc:3 }, { abc: 4 },{ abc:5 }, { abc: 6 }]

Answer (score 0):

> **Good question** you can't simply spread the arrays so a good **one liner**
>   for this would be.

```
state = {
  one : [ { abc:1 }, { abc: 2 }],
  two : [ { abc:3 }, { abc: 4 }], 
  three : [ { abc:5 }, { abc: 6 }]
}

var result = Object.values(state).flat()  // solution

console.log(result)
```

Comment: the same awnser is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53060808/3519009).

Comment: yeah you are right.. @NarendraJadhav 
Probably didn't see it or the previous answer was posted while I was into solving it.. 
Thanks :)